# Как сделать список с изображениями и текстом на Java?

Tags: java, списки

Нужно сделать список на [java](/questions/tagged/java), содержащий панели `JPanel`, которые включают в себя изображение, текст и чекбокс.

[image: Список]

Вроде этого, только под каждым нужны чекбоксы.

Пробовал так:

```
public static JList<JPanel> itemsArray;
public static DefaultListModel<JPanel> listModel;
```

Но после добавления добавляется не панелька, а отладочное представление (Не знаю как именно это назвать) 
В общем вот:

[image: Отладочный вид]

Для каждого элемента я хочу использовать отдельный класс `ItemComponent`

Количество элементов может быть неограниченным и заранее не известно. Плюс они должны добавляться динамически

Comment: Сделайте панель со всеми этими элементами и засуньте в `JScrollPane`.

Comment: @zRrr количество элементов заранее не известно

Comment: Думаю может подойти вариант сделать List<GridPane>. В каждом элементе грида, в одном столбецe создавать нужные тебе элементы.

Comment: @Herrgott Вы можете написать свою реализацию `ListCellRenderer`, на которой будут нужные компоненты в правильном положении, проблема в том, что элементы `JList` - это картинки, а не полноценные компоненты, как напр. в Android, т.е. вы можете добавить кнопку или чекбокс к рендереру, но сами по себе они не будут нажиматься, порождать события и т.п. Поэтому используют или `JTable` с `TableCellRenderer` и `TableCellEditor`, или свою панель, на которой раскладывают компоненты, как хочется.

Answer (score 1):

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final File list[] = new File("./pictures/").listFiles();
    assert list != null;
    for (File aList : list) {
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("my icon");
        panel.add(label);
        try {
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(aList)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Надеюсь, я Вас правильно понял, что Вы хотите сделать